# TypeError in Python due to empty sequence

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, function

I am using a simple script:

```
def get_stories(self, f):
     data = [([], [u'Where', u'is', u'the', u'apple', u'?'],u'office')]
     flatten = lambda data: reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, data)
     data = [(flatten(story), q, answer) for story, q, answer in data]
     return data
```

**TypeError: reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value**

But data is not empty !!

Why is this error happening.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: `story` is the `[]`. You're trying to `reduce` over that.

Comment: So break it into pieces and make sure each of them works. Or if you're having trouble understanding your flatten one-liner, don't write it as a one-liner, write out the loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message gives a good hint about how to solve the problem, by stating that there is "no initial value". Here's what docs for [reduce](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) have to say:

> **reduce**(*function*, *iterable*[, *initializer*])
>
> Apply function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of iterable, from left to right, so as to reduce the iterable to a single
>   value. For example, reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>   calculates ((((1+2)+3)+4)+5). The left argument, x, is the accumulated
>   value and the right argument, y, is the update value from the
>   iterable. **If the optional initializer is present, it is placed before
>   the items of the iterable in the calculation, and serves as a default
>   when the iterable is empty**. If initializer is not given and iterable
>   contains only one item, the first item is returned. [*emphasis added*]

So your `flatten` function should look like this:

```
    flatten = lambda data: reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, data, [])
```